# Nothing in $_POST (Http request / Angular / PHP)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm stuck with a simple issue, but I did not find any answer on Web. So, here is my code

```
const URL = 'http://(...)/scripts/Fiabilisation_Unique.php';
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type: application/json' 
   'reportProgress': 'true'
})
(...)
onClickAdresse(f : NgForm){
var adresse : Adresse= (f.value);
console.log(adresse); //{adresse : "just a french adresse"}
this.http.post(URL, adresse, httpOptions).subscribe(
  (event) => {
    this.temp=(event); // handle event here
    },
  () => {
  console.log("Observable done ! ");
    }
  );
}
```

But in my file 'Fiabilisation_Unique.php", when I try a simple : `print_r($_POST);` it prints me : `Array(
)`

I am pretty sure that my problem is not that complicate but I just don't figure out what is the issue. I also know that answer should not be that far but...

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: this.temp= event

Comment: Yes, but it does not change anything to my problem :)

Comment: can you post the tempate of your form please ?

Comment: `<form #Adresse="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickAdresse(Adresse)"novalidate> 
    <mat-form-field >    <input matInput required  maxlength ="150" ngModel #adresse="ngModel" name="adresse"  id="adresse" placeholder="Adresse">    <mat-form-field> <br/>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]=!Adresse.valid>Lancer l'éligibilité</button>
                </form>`

Comment: Are you sure post returns something ?, it's a best practice, but not always done. Some webapi return the new object, some return the id, some return de url. What does console.log( event )  report ?

Comment: Inspect your page and see the Network. I don't think this is angular's error.

Comment: wFitz, I did (event) => console.log(event) in my subscribe, but nothing is printed at all...

Comment: mintquan, nothing is reported as error in the Network, until the php (because it's empty)...

Answer (score 0):

Your `HttpOptions` are not correct. Wrong quotation and reportProgress is misplaced:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  reportProgress: true
});
```

But if you enable the `reportProgress`, the subscribe will receive multiple events from `HttpEventType.Sent` to `HttpEventType.Done`. But I guess that is what you want :)

Comment: Ok so now the response of console.log(event) is : {type: 0}
{type: 1, loaded: 31, total: 31}
HttpHeaderResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://xxx/scripts/Fiabilisation_Unique.php", ok: true, …}headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}ok: truestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: 2url: "http://(...)/scripts/Fiabilisation_Unique.php"__proto__: HttpResponseBase
 {type: 3, loaded: 1312, total: 1312}

Answer (score 0):

Ok Everyone, I finally found the answer. As expected, It was really easy.

I just add a `$angularJSData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`
 in my PHP code.

Thanks everyone !